# TeamCity Custom Notifier Not Running

Tags: java, build, teamcity

So, I've created a simple team city notifier which will just log some information to my C drive at the moment, but whenever a build is triggered on TeamCity, the notifier doesn't run. I am not sure what I am missing. Here's what I have thus far. The MyLogger class just gets a simple java.util.logging.Logger object that creates a log on the C drive.

Here is my implementation of the Notificator interface:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import jetbrains.buildServer.Build;
import jetbrains.buildServer.notification.Notificator;
import jetbrains.buildServer.notification.NotificatorRegistry;
import jetbrains.buildServer.responsibility.ResponsibilityEntry;
import jetbrains.buildServer.responsibility.TestNameResponsibilityEntry;
import jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SBuildType;
import jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SProject;
import jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.SRunningBuild;
import jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.STest;
import jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.mute.MuteInfo;
import jetbrains.buildServer.tests.TestName;
import jetbrains.buildServer.users.SUser;
import jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsRoot;

public class TestNotificator implements Notificator {

    private Logger log;

    public TestNotificator(NotificatorRegistry nR) {
        log = MyLogger.getLogger();
        log.info("Registering the Notificator");
        nR.register(this);
    }

    public void doNotifications(SRunningBuild arg0) {
        log.info("Do Notifications has been called");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Test Notificator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNotificatorType() {
        return "testNotificator";
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildFailed(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        log.info("Build has failed");
        doNotifications(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildFailedToStart(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildFailing(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildProbablyHanging(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildStarted(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyBuildSuccessful(SRunningBuild arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        log.info("Build was Successfull");
        doNotifications(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyLabelingFailed(Build arg0, VcsRoot arg1, Throwable arg2,
            Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleAssigned(SBuildType arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleAssigned(TestNameResponsibilityEntry arg0,
            TestNameResponsibilityEntry arg1, SProject arg2, Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleAssigned(Collection<TestName> arg0,
            ResponsibilityEntry arg1, SProject arg2, Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleChanged(SBuildType arg0, Set<SUser> arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleChanged(TestNameResponsibilityEntry arg0,
            TestNameResponsibilityEntry arg1, SProject arg2, Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyResponsibleChanged(Collection<TestName> arg0,
            ResponsibilityEntry arg1, SProject arg2, Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyTestsMuted(Collection<STest> arg0, MuteInfo arg1,
            Set<SUser> arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyTestsUnmuted(Collection<STest> arg0, MuteInfo arg1,
            SUser arg2, Set<SUser> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here's the build-server-plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans default-autowire="constructor">
  <bean id="testNotifier" class="com.testnot.TestNotificator"/>
</beans>
```

I package up the class and build-server-plugin.xml together in the same jar. In the jar there are two separate directories there is com.testnot and META-INF. Maybe I'm not packaging them up correctly. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help what-so-ever would be greatly appreciated. I have been using the example found [here.](http://code.google.com/p/buildbunny/wiki/CreateTeamcityNotifier)

Comment: Beuller, Beuller, anyone, anyone... ? lol. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after finally finding the logs, I discovered that you must compile the plugins with Java 6, it is not compatible with Java 7. After this change, the plugins are now running.